# Can you help me solve Windows 10 strange performance issue

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance

I have this really strange performance problem with Windows 10. And I am not entirely sure what is causing it.

When ever I boot my computer up after it's been off for some time, and load in... if I try running any game, there is some severe performance problems going on. There will be a lot of micro stutters happening that will make the game completely unplayable. Along with massive frame drops, and terrible audio burping.

However, if I were to restart the computer, or turn it off and turn it back on within a few seconds these problems seem to completely go away.

I know it's not the graphics card. As I've recently swapped out the old and put in a new. And this problem occurs under both CPUs.

I have reinstalled windows 10. The problem occurred on my old installation. The new installation seemed to work ok for a while, and then had the same problems all over again.

I haven't Memtest 86 my ram yet, but will likely try that later on today.

It could very well be Windows 10 doing something really stupid. But I have no idea what.

My current hardware is...

16 Gigs of GSKILL ram
AMD FX8120
Sapphire Nitro+ RX480 8GB

Comment: try turning off superfetch, i've had issues with it before using too much resources, in a run box type services.msc , look for superfetch, disable it and reboot

Comment: Since this is an AMD chipset, I've had a similar issue (although with an old computer) caused by the SATA controller. Make sure to manually install the proper drivers, and be very careful in case you are plugged into a third-party controller on the motherboard.

Comment: Do you have any antivirus running? I have found with some AV software (Nod32 and Antivir), the initial scan uses a lot of resources. Does the performance improve a while after booting?

Comment: @RyanIG I'll look into that. Though what is the purpose of SuperFetch?

Comment: @fragamemnon The sata controller? That seems pretty odd, but I'll go ahead and uninstall the drivers for it. And reinstall the drivers from gigabyte.

Comment: @Alex I only have Windows defender.

Comment: @moonshineTheleocat It's odd and a shot in the dark with a small chance of working, hence why a comment. :)

Comment: @fragamemnon Well... it'd probably help if I actually had AMD's Chipset drivers installed. It looks like that is no longer included in their standard driver installation.

Comment: @fragamemnon Alright, it looks like the issue is actually being caused by the SATA controller. But the problem is that the Marel 91xx SATA 6G controller does not have an available driver for Windows 10.

It also appears that windows 10 does not want to use the one included with the Catalyst/Radeon software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that I have found the solution after doing a bit of research on google. Apparently the issue isn't caused by a driver malfunction. But the issue is actually caused by a Windows feature that does not make any sense.

The cause is created by the Windows Power options.

Press the windows key, type in "Power Options", and then select the control panel dialogue.

When the window is open, look to the left and select "Choose what power buttons do"

From here, you need to click "Change Settings that are currently unavailable".

Afterwards uncheck "Turn on Fast startup"

It appears that this causes windows to take some short cuts when you start up and power down. This causes a whole mess of problems, and apparently this won't happen if you choose restart.

For anyone else having this problem, this may be a solution to it. Try it if you see "System Interrupts" in the task explorer above 1% on a regular basis.

Comment: I would have never guessed. If i get my hands on a similar machine, I'll make sure to play around with it. I suppose this is specific only to Windows 10?

Comment: To my knowledge, yes. Maybe.